# Comparar valores em real e injetar o valor no input com Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pessoal tenho um form onde tenho um campo para digitar valores. Esse campo tem uma mascara em jquery que formata os valores para real brasileiro 0,00, função mvalor, que esta abaixo, porém esse campo só pode aceitar valores em real maior que 25,00, ou seja preciso validar esse campo para que o usuário só possa digitar valores maiores do que 25,00. Um amigo me passo essa função abaixo, ela funciona bem, se alguém digita um valor menor do que 25,00 mostra uma mensagem de erro avisando e injeta o valor 25,00 no campo input, nesse formato em real, porém se eu digitar um valor acima 999,00, por exemplo 1.000,00 acontece um erro porque entende que o valor digitado é menor que 25,00, eu percebi que isso ocorre porque a função verifica somente os numero antes do ponto, se antes do ponto for maior que 25 independentemente de ser real ou numérico blz, mas se alguém digitar 1.000,00 que é menor que 25,00, onde o numero antes do ponto é apenas 1 dai ela não faz o que se propõe e da um erro. Se eu digitar no campo 25.000,00 dai da certo, com isso percebo que valida apenas os numero que vem antes do ponto, o que vem depois a função ignora.

Eu nao tenho conhecimento suficiente em jquery pra corrigir esse problema, se alguém puder me ajudar, ficarei muito grato.

```
<script>


    $('input[name=amount]').focusout(function() {
    var valorDigitado = parseFloat($(this).val());
    if (valorDigitado < 25.00) {
       $('input[name="amount"]').val("25,00");
       showError_amount();
       } else {
        $("#error_amount").hide();
       }

  });

  function mvalor(i) {
  var v = i.value.replace(/\D/g,'');
  v = (v/100).toFixed(2) + '';
  v = v.replace(".", ",");
  v = v.replace(/(\d)(\d{3})(\d{3}),/g, "$1.$2.$3,");
  v = v.replace(/(\d)(\d{3}),/g, "$1.$2,");
  i.value = v;
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1.000,00` é considerado menor que `25.00` porque no JavaScript as casas decimais são separadas por ponto, ou seja, `1.000,00` é a mesma coisa que `1.00` ou apenas `1`, o que é menor que `25`.

Você consegue resolver retirando do valor digitado o ponto do milhar e substituindo a vírgula por ponto. Ao digitar `1.000,00`, irá ficar `1000.00` (mil), que é maior que `25` (ou `25.00`).

É só fazer dois replaces no valor dentro do `parseFloat`:

```
parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/\./g,"").replace(",","."))
```

Aqui `.replace(/\./g,"")` substitui todos os possíveis pontos separadores de milhar que a máscara insere.

Veja:

```js
$('input[name=amount]').focusout(function() {
 var valorDigitado = parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/\./g,"").replace(",","."));
 if (valorDigitado < 25.00) {
    $('input[name="amount"]').val("25,00");
    showError_amount();
    } else {
     $("#error_amount").hide();
    }

});

function mvalor(i) {
var v = i.value.replace(/\D/g,'');
v = (v/100).toFixed(2) + '';
v = v.replace(".", ",");
v = v.replace(/(\d)(\d{3})(\d{3}),/g, "$1.$2.$3,");
v = v.replace(/(\d)(\d{3}),/g, "$1.$2,");
i.value = v;
}

function showError_amount(){
  $("#error_amount").show().text("Menor que 25");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="amount" oninput="mvalor(this)">
<div id="error_amount"></div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, isso resolveu meu problema.